# VUE 3 SETUP @vue/compiler-sfc

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

> Error: [@vue/compiler-sfc] Unresolvable type reference or unsupported built-in utility type.

I can't use `InputHTMLAttributes` like props in defineProps

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { type InputHTMLAttributes } from "vue";

const props = withDefaults(
    defineProps<InputHTMLAttributes>(),
    {
        type: "text",
    }
);
</script>
<template>
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label for="" class="text-xs text-gray-600 capitalize font-semibold"
            >name</label
        >
        <input
            :="props"
            type="text"
            placeholder="English"
            class="w-full text-xs py-2 px-3 outline-primary rounded-md border"
        />
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error at `<InputHTMLAttributes}>`. Please [edit] your question to contain valid code. FYI, it's best to copy / paste your actual code

Comment: i fix my quesion. but the problem is  still there

Comment: InputHTMLAttributes is not generic

Comment: Seems to work when I paste your code into a [playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/). Am I missing something?